# spreadsheet missing data for corresponding cells

Tags: spreadsheet, missing-data

I have a problem with missing data of corresponding column.
Column A has unique value which corresponds to specific cities in Col B. But few cells in col B is empty. It is long spreadsheet. How to fill col B from the values of corresponding col A automatically?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcwRE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use if condition available with syntax ISBLANK().